# rsync issue failed: No such file or directory (2)

Tags: rsync

I am trying to use rsync files from my home directory. The error I get is:

`rsync: link_stat "/home/xxx/.mozilla/firefox/**/*.sqlite" failed: No such file or directory (2)`

I have checked and the file exists, but this error keeps happening.

This is the command I'm using:

```
HOME_FILES=/home/xxx/

rsync -v --copy-links --recursive --files-from=rsync_files $HOME_FILES $DESTDIR/rs/
```

Comment: Are you sure in '/home/xxx/.mozilla/firefox/**/*.sqlite' exist? It looks like very strange to use asterix characters in directory.

Comment: I understood that was the way to specify wildcards in <filename> to rsync when using --files-from=<filename>.

for example, /home/xxx/.mozilla/firefox/jb48akxy.default/places.sqlite does exist; when using this instead of the wildcard format, rsync works.

( I want to avoid having to specify the intermediate directory, so I on't need to edit <rsync_files> when I create a new Fx profile.)

Answer (score 0):

`--files-from` parameter does not support regex or wildcards.
I think you have to read the man page of rsync:

```
   --include-from=FILE
          This option is related to the --include option, but it specifies
          a FILE that contains include patterns  (one  per  line).   Blank
          lines  in  the  file  and  lines  starting  with  ’;’ or ’#’ are
          ignored.  If FILE is -, the list  will  be  read  from  standard
          input.
```

Comment: thanks - but the parameter does not contain wildcards (if literally reads "--include-from=rsync_files", where "rsync_files" is the name of the file); the file it points to does (and those are the "patterns" mentioned in your text)